# MVC is it possible to customize or override view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Its a typical scenario, every model of application inherits one base class. This base class contains some property which behaves differently on different parameters which comes in form of query string.

I want to have a centralized mechanism to handle the scenario like when controller returns a view I catch the model and supply the value in property.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own CustomActionResult class. Something like this:

```
public class CustomActionResult : ActionResult
{
     public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
     {
          // your logic here
     }
}

public ActionResult YourAction() 
{
     return new CustomActionResult (viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, pretty open-ended question. If you just want to calculate/fetch some extra information to display in a particular View, you can use the **ViewBag** object in your controller.

```
ViewBag.Greeting = "Welcome, " + User.FirstName;
```

Then, in your Razor code you would access this via `@ViewBag.Greeting` (or `<%=ViewBag.Greeting%>` in ASPX). The ViewBag inherits from ASP.NET's **ViewData** object, which is (effectively) dynamically typed and will accept any object structure you throw at it. In short, very powerful, easy to use, but can lead to **problems at run-time that other methods would catch at compile time**.

Of course, you might have a problem  that the data in your class (or data source) is not in the correct form for your View to make use of. This is very common when developing an application that interfaces with an existing ecosystem (i.e. most of the code you'll ever write). In this case, **view models** are your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model

In addition to the **/Models** folder in your project, create a **/ViewModels** namespace and match these to your views. So, for your **/Views/Product/Details.cshtml** you create a **/ViewModels/Product/Details.cs** class and either pass in the id (or the model) as an argument. Make using you add a `using MyProject.ViewModels` in your controller though!